# Handling ajax session timeout using $loginRequiredAjaxResponse in yii

Tags: ajax, yii, session-timeout, http-redirect, yii-components

I am struggling to find a way for handling ajax session timeouts so that the user is redirected to the login page and after login they should be redirected to their original location. As per the yii documentation, it can be achieved using the [$loginRequiredAjaxResponse](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#loginRequiredAjaxResponse-detail) property. I am not sure how to implement it practically. I tried assigning this property the URL where the user should be redirected after login, but that did not work. For non ajax request, there is a straight forward method [loginRequired()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#loginRequired-detail) to achive this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Yii framework wiki tutorial, this will help you to resolve your issue -

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/321/using-loginrequiredajaxresponse-to-solve-ajax-session-timeout/

Comment: then this and get idea from this wiki - http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/751/check-users-online-user-last-activity-user-last-ip/